# Is too much Subquery can cause Internal Server Error 500?

Tags: mysql, subquery, internal-server-error

```
// initialized null variables
        $sql_for_training = null;
        $sql_for_screening = null;
        $sql_for_all = null;
        $sqlforpositions = null;

        $sql0 = 'SELECT * FROM lib_positions';

        $result0 = $db->fetchAll($sql0);


        $city_query = "";
        // append additional query
        if(isset($data['region_id'])){
            $sql_for_training.=" AND p.region = '".$data['region_id']."' ";
            $sql_for_screening.=" AND p.region_address = ".$data['region_id']." ";
            $sql_for_all.= " AND ".$data['table'].".region_id = ".$data['region_id'];
            // $sqlforpositions = "";
        }
        if(isset($data['province_id'])){
            $sql_for_training.=" AND p.province = ".$data['province_id']." ";
            $sql_for_screening.=" AND p.province_address = ".$data['province_id']." ";
            $sql_for_all.= " AND ".$data['table'].".province_id = ".$data['province_id'];
            // $sqlforpositions = "";
        }
        if(isset($data['city_id'])){
            $sql_for_training.=" AND p.city_municipality = ".$data['city_id']." ";
            $sql_for_screening.=" AND p.city_municipality_address = ".$data['city_id']." ";
            $sql_for_all.= " AND ".$data['table'].".city_municipality_id = ".$data['city_id'];
            $sqlforpositions = "";
            $city_query = "LIMIT 1";
        }

        // build query string.
        $sql = "SELECT ".$data['table'].".id AS table_id, ".$data['table'].".".$data['type']."_desc AS ".$data['type']."_desc,
                    l_p.position_desc as position_desc,

                    (SELECT count(p.id) FROM tbl_personal_info AS p
                        INNER JOIN tbl_screening AS s ON p.id = s.candidate_id
                        INNER JOIN tbl_position_applied AS p_a ON s.candidate_id = p_a.candidate_id
                        WHERE p.".$data['type']."_address = ".$data['table'].".id
                        AND p_a.position_id = l_p.id
                        ".$sql_for_screening.") AS screening,


                    (SELECT count(p.id) FROM tbl_personal_info AS p 
                        INNER JOIN tbl_screening AS s ON p.id = s.candidate_id
                        INNER JOIN tbl_position_applied AS p_a ON s.candidate_id = p_a.candidate_id
                        WHERE s.screening_id = 6 AND
                        p.".$data['type']." = ".$data['table'].".id 
                        AND p_a.position_id = l_p.id
                        ".$sql_for_screening.") AS prescreened,

                    (SELECT count(p.id) FROM tbl_personal_info AS p 
                        INNER JOIN tbl_screening AS s ON p.id = s.candidate_id
                        INNER JOIN tbl_position_applied AS p_a ON s.candidate_id = p_a.candidate_id 
                        WHERE s.screening_id = 4 AND 
                        p.".$data['type']." = ".$data['table'].".id
                        AND p_a.position_id = l_p.id
                        ".$sql_for_screening.") AS qualified,

                    (SELECT count(p.id) FROM tbl_personal_info AS p 
                        INNER JOIN tbl_training AS tr ON p.id = tr.candidate_id
                        INNER JOIN tbl_position_applied AS p_a ON tr.candidate_id = p_a.candidate_id 
                        WHERE p.".$data['type']." = ".$data['table'].".id
                        AND p_a.position_id = l_p.id
                        ".$sql_for_training.") AS training,

                    (SELECT count(p.id) FROM tbl_personal_info AS p 
                        INNER JOIN tbl_training AS tr ON p.id = tr.candidate_id 
                        INNER JOIN tbl_position_applied AS p_a ON tr.candidate_id = p_a.candidate_id 
                        WHERE  tr.status = 2 AND p.".$data['type']." = ".$data['table'].".id
                        AND p_a.position_id = l_p.id
                        ".$sql_for_training.") AS failed,

                    (SELECT count(p.id) FROM tbl_personal_info AS p 
                        INNER JOIN tbl_training AS tr ON p.id = tr.candidate_id 
                        INNER JOIN tbl_position_applied AS p_a ON tr.candidate_id = p_a.candidate_id 
                        WHERE  tr.status = 1 AND p.".$data['type']." = ".$data['table'].".id
                        AND p_a.position_id = l_p.id
                        ".$sql_for_training.") AS passed,

                    (SELECT count(p.id) FROM tbl_personal_info AS p 
                        INNER JOIN tbl_requirements AS t_r ON p.id = t_r.candidate_id
                        INNER JOIN tbl_position_applied AS p_a ON p.id = p_a.candidate_id 
                        WHERE (SELECT count(t_r.candidate_id) FROM tbl_requirements AS t_r WHERE candidate_id = p.id) = (SELECT count(l_r.id) FROM lib_requirements as l_r)
                        AND p_a.position_id = l_p.id
                        ".$sql_for_training.") AS completed,

                    t.target as target,
                    t.screening_target as screening_target,
                    t.training_target as training_target

                FROM ".$data['table']."
                RIGHT JOIN tbl_target as t on ".$data['table'].".id = t.area_id
                LEFT JOIN lib_positions as l_p on t.position_id = l_p.id
                WHERE t.area_type ='".$data['type']."'"
                .$sql_for_all;

        // execute query string
        // echo "<pre>".$sql."</pre>";


        $result = $db->fetchAll($sql);

        $db->closeConnection();
        //Zend_Debug::dump($result);

        //die();
        return $result;
```

When i'm fetching 10 rows of it. it result as i wanted. but when the query is trying to fetch morethan 15 rows of it. i result Internal Server 500 error. i currently have 2300 row in my tbl_personal_info. 7 region in my tbl_region and around 200+ provinces in my lib_provinces table and 1000+ lib_city_municipality. am i doing it wrong with my query? or i'm just using too much subquery? Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: Could you add the resulting queries that work and the ones that don't work?

Comment: but that is the only query i use. when the row is i'm fetching more than a count it results into internal server error. and when i'm fetching less. it result as i wanted. maybe it has to do with execution time? but i have max_execution time of 600 and 545M of limit. how's that?

Comment: am i doing it wrong with using too much subquery? and on the top of that each subquery has Inner JOin to it. does it make my query bad? what? the fastest alternative?

Answer (score 0):

PROBLEM SOLVED

SELECT
                lr.id AS table_id,
                lr.".$data['type']."_desc AS ".$data['type']."_desc,
                lp.position_desc,
                count(lr.id) AS count_area,
                count(pi.id) AS screening,
                count(case ts.screening_id when 6 then 1 else null end) AS prescreened,
                count(case ts.screening_id when 4 then 1 else null end) AS qualified,
                count(tt.id) AS training,
                count(case tt.status when 2 then 1 else null end) AS failed,
                count(case tt.status when 1 then 1 else null end) AS passed,
                0 AS completed,
                tar.target as target,
                tar.screening_target as screening_target,
                tar.training_target as training_target

```
            FROM tbl_personal_info AS pi
            RIGHT JOIN tbl_position_applied AS tpa ON pi.id = tpa.candidate_id
            RIGHT JOIN ".$data['table']." AS lr ON pi.".$data['type']." = lr.id
            LEFT JOIN lib_positions AS lp ON tpa.position_id = lp.id
            INNER JOIN tbl_screening AS ts ON pi.id = ts.candidate_id
            LEFT JOIN tbl_training AS tt ON pi.id = tt.candidate_id
            LEFT JOIN tbl_target AS tar ON lr.id = tar.area_id

            WHERE tar.area_type = '".$data['type']."'
            AND tar.position_id = lp.id
            ".$sql_for_all."
            GROUP BY lr.id,tpa.position_id
            ORDER BY lr.id ASC,lp.id ASC
```

i used this improved query. :))